# Trying to get StandardOutput after running a console process

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application

I can run a console process using the following C# code. The goal is also to collect all the output from such process:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

proc.StartInfo.Arguments = commandLine;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "signtool.exe";
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

proc.Start();

if (proc.WaitForExit(10000))
{
    Debug.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
}
```

What I receive is this:

> "Done Adding Additional Store\r\n"

But when I do the same from a Windows command line I get this:

```
Done Adding Additional Store
SignTool Error: File not found: C:\SomeBadFile.exe
```

Why am I getting only the first line of output with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as the line you are missing seems like an error message, should you not be looking at [Process.StandardError Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror.aspx)

> When a Process writes text to its standard error stream, that text is
>   normally displayed on the console. By redirecting the StandardError
>   stream, you can manipulate or suppress the error output of a process.
>   For example, you can filter the text, format it differently, or write
>   the output to both the console and a designated log file.

Comment: Oops. You're correct. I totally forgot about the `StandardError`. Yeah, it's there...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried redirecting and watching StandardError too?  It seem likley that this is output to the error stream.

Comment: Thanks too. It is in the StandardError.